# Allocating Memory to char Pointers for Writing

Tags: c, pointers

So, I'm trying to write into a buffer declared within the `main` function by allocating memory in the function in which I'm going to write to it, I noticed that passing a char pointer the memory is allocated but can only be used locally, while passing a pointer that points to a char pointer the allocated memory is "visible" even inside the `main` function.

This is the code where I allocate memory in the heap to the two pointers:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void AllocateMemoryToPtr(char* ptr)
{
    if (!(ptr = malloc(32)))
        exit(1);
}

void AllocateMemoryToDoublePtr(char** ptr)
{
    if (!(*ptr = malloc(32))) 
        exit(1);
}

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    char* Ptr = NULL;
    char* DoublePtr = NULL;
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("Ptr\t\tADDRESS\t\tBEFORE\tmalloc\t-> %p\n", Ptr);
    printf("Ptr\t\tVALUE\t\tBEFORE\tmalloc\t-> %s\n", Ptr);
    printf("\n");
    printf("DoublePtr\tADDRESS\t\tBEFORE\tmalloc\t-> %p\n", DoublePtr);
    printf("DoublePtr\tVALUE\t\tBEFORE\tmalloc\t-> %s\n", DoublePtr);
    printf("\n");

    AllocateMemoryToPtr(Ptr);
    AllocateMemoryToDoublePtr(&DoublePtr);

    printf("\n");
    printf("Ptr\t\tADDRESS\t\tAFTER\tmalloc\t-> %p\n", Ptr);
    printf("Ptr\t\tVALUE\t\tAFTER\tmalloc\t-> %s\n", Ptr);
    printf("\n");
    printf("DoublePtr\tADDRESS\t\tAFTER\tmalloc\t-> %p\n", DoublePtr);
    printf("DoublePtr\tVALUE\t\tAFTER\tmalloc\t-> %s\n", DoublePtr);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone clarify my ideas on how to write in external buffers using pointers please?

Comment: You've stated that in the first paragraph: the first function does not affect the variable in `main` but the second one does. Note that you are dereferencing `NULL` pointers before these functions are called, in `printf` using `%s`. Following the function calls, `char* Ptr` is still `NULL` and you also have a memory leak. And `char* DoublePtr` still can't be treated as a string, because the memory pointed to contains uninitialised data.

Comment: Ok, but then to write inside the variable in main I must pass a double pointer?

Answer (score 0):

C is pass-by-value. That is, function parameters are like function local variables, modifying them does not modify original. To achieve pass-by-reference, you need to pass a pointer to original.

---

```
void AllocateMemoryToPtr(char* ptr)
{
    if (!(ptr = malloc(32)))
        exit(1);
}
```

`char*` is pointer to char buffer and allows you to modify the buffer, but not what the original pointer points to.

So you have memory leak here, `ptr` is lost when function returns.

---

```
void AllocateMemoryToDoublePtr(char** ptr)
{
    if (!(*ptr = malloc(32))) 
        exit(1);
}
```

`char**` is pointer to pointer, and allows you to modify the original pointer (and also the buffer it points to, of course).

So this does what you want.

Comment: Got It, thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to return the addres of the allocated block, like this:

```
char * AllocateMemoryToPtr(int size)
{
    if (!(char *ptr = malloc(size)))
        exit(1);
    return ptr;
}
```

and in `main`:

```
int size = 32;
char *ptr = AllocateMemoryToPtr(size);
```

Comment: If I return the allocated memory, then is it possible to free it when no more needed or does it remain allocated?

Comment: Any dynamically allocated memory remains allocated during the lifetime of the program, unless freed explicitly. Most operating systems will free memory after terminated processes, but don't rely on that. You should allways free memory when it is not needed anymore.